# Performance enhancement in DAX query

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have Power BI DAX query used in a measure. It takes longer time to execute. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
MEASURE FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[Measure 4] =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        CONTAINS (
            DIM_ANALYTIC_STRUCT_ACCOUNT,
            DIM_ANALYTIC_STRUCT_ACCOUNT[STRUCTURE_NODE (groups)], "1 - CURRENT ASSETS"
        ), SUM ( FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[BALANCE] ),
        CONTAINS (
            DIM_ANALYTIC_STRUCT_ACCOUNT,
            DIM_ANALYTIC_STRUCT_ACCOUNT[STRUCTURE_NODE (groups)], "2 - NON - CURRENT ASSETS"
        ), SUM ( FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[BALANCE] ),
        SUM ( FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[BALANCE] ) * -1
    )
```

Performance Result on DAX Studio:

[image: DAX_Studio]

Comment: Hi!

Please clarify your question, you can follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Some tips: 
Formulating your example code and sharing the data model with us is a good idea.
What is the actual performance, and which performance do you want to earn?

Comment: @kesadae11 I have mentioned the coding above. PBI Report will use direct query method to fetch data. Currently it has actual performance as per below image (8549ms in total). It's better to reduce that for below 2000 ms.

https://ibb.co/0FVQr45

Comment: Can you please share the performance result screen, if possible on DAX Studio or .vpax file ?

Comment: @OzanSen Please use below link for the performance result screenshot. I have uploaded it to below sites since, this wont' give access to upload images I think
https://ibb.co/0FVQr45

Comment: Thank you for the file. 10 SE queries seems to be a big problem; but Most of the workload are on the SE which is quite good. I need to examine if contains() are the actual culprit? Stay safe!

Comment: Thank you @OzanSen. Can you please help me with this to rectify this issue? I'm still newbie to Power BI and DAX queries. I'm really grateful if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this code, see if It solves your problem. I tried to write it without contains() function.

```
MEASURE FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[Measure 4] =
    SUMX (
        FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL,
        VAR Balance =
            SWITCH (
                RELATED ( DIM_ANALYTIC_STRUCT_ACCOUNT[STRUCTURE_NODE (groups)] ),
                "1 - CURRENT ASSETS", FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[BALANCE],
                "2 - NON - CURRENT ASSETS", FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[BALANCE],
                FACT_CONSOL_BALANCE_OL[BALANCE] * -1
            )
        RETURN
            Balance
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked pretty well for me